# можно ли отправлять сообщения в группы через личку бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Допустим, можно ли сделать так, что бы мое сообщение боту в лс передавалось в какую либо группу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, для этого имеется метод [copyMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#copymessage), который просто копирует сообщение, либо метод [forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage), который пересылает его.

Пример пересылки сообщения

```py
bot.forward_message(chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id)
```

`chat_id` -> ID чата, **куда** сообщение будет переслано (в Вашем случае ID Вашей группы)

`from_chat_id` -> ID чата, **откуда** пересылается сообщение (в Вашем случае ID чата с Вашим ботом)

`message_id` -> ID сообщения, лежит в объекте `Message`

Comment: Спасибо , я понял